# Adding functions to a pipeline based on an argument

Tags: r, apply, purrr

I am trying to write a function that calls another function multiple times in its body. I am hoping to control the number of such function calls and their respective target by using an argument, but this becomes tricky due to the structure of pipelines. Imagine this simple example of mutating columns. I am fully aware that this is not the greatest example as you wouldn't call mutate multiple times for different targets, but bear with me. This is just a standin example, so it is important that each mutate call corresponds to a string supplied via the `cols` argument.

```r
library(dplyr)

scale_cols <- function(data, cols = c("mpg", "cyl")) {
  
  processed_data <- data |> 
    mutate("mpg" = scale(mpg)) |> 
    mutate("cyl" = scale(cyl))
  
  return(processed_data)
}

scale_cols(mtcars)
#>                             mpg        cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am
#> Mazda RX4            0.15088482 -0.1049878 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1
#> Mazda RX4 Wag        0.15088482 -0.1049878 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1
#> Datsun 710           0.44954345 -1.2248578 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1
#> Hornet 4 Drive       0.21725341 -0.1049878 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0
#> Hornet Sportabout   -0.23073453  1.0148821 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0
#> Valiant             -0.33028740 -0.1049878 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0
#> Duster 360          -0.96078893  1.0148821 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0
#> Merc 240D            0.71501778 -1.2248578 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0
#> Merc 230             0.44954345 -1.2248578 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Currently which columns are to be transformed is hardcoded, but I would prefer being able to choose the columnsfor transformation by using the `cols` argument. Is it possible to map or apply the mutate function over the `cols` elements so that in the end a fully functional pipeline is created? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Use `across()`. `data |> mutate(across(all_of(cols), scale))`. See the `?across` help page for description and more examples.

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. It is essential that another function call is added to the pipeline for each element of the argument. This is just a standin example, not the actual problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: Then it would help to create an example that is closer to the problem you are actually trying to solve. The `across()` function will recognize any of the tidy-select options for choosing columns. It's not clear why that wouldn't work.

Comment: well, I am trying to add fitted models to a stack based on the argument, but that's a huge hassle for anyone to set up locally since it involves fitting multiple models first. This is an easy way to describe the problem. I need to control the function calls in the argument and I suspect that there is a way to solve this iteratively by applying or mapping over the arguments provided.

Comment: Does it have to be a pipe? Why not loop over columns and do a simple assignment like `data[[col]] = scale(data[[col]])` ?

Comment: OP initially rejects comments to the effect that "there are better ways to do this", insists that a piped solution is required and that their representation of the problem is unambiguously the best.  They then accept an answer which is not piped.  I find this utterly inconsistent.

Comment: I apologize for the badly asked question and the problems that resulted from that. All I intended was to make this easy for people who were interested while achieving the exact opposite. Thank you for your help, however, it proved very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds to me as though you want to iteratively apply a function once for each element of a passed vector, and for the result to include the changes cumulatively. The non-standard evaluation involved in `mutate`, as well as there being better ways to carry out this particular operation probably makes it a suboptimal example.

However, the basic concept of what you are trying to do is performed by the base R function `Reduce`, which will take a starting argument (e.g. the input data frame), and iteratively apply a function of two variables (the output of the last iteration and the next member of the `cols` vector)

```r
scale_cols <- function(data, cols = c("mpg", "cyl")) {
  
  Reduce(function(x, y) { 
    x[[y]] <- scale(x[[y]]) 
    return(x)
    }, x = cols, init = data)
}
```

Resulting in:

```r
scale_cols(mtcars)
#>                             mpg        cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am
#> Mazda RX4            0.15088482 -0.1049878 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1
#> Mazda RX4 Wag        0.15088482 -0.1049878 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1
#> Datsun 710           0.44954345 -1.2248578 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1
#> Hornet 4 Drive       0.21725341 -0.1049878 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0
#> Hornet Sportabout   -0.23073453  1.0148821 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0
#> Valiant             -0.33028740 -0.1049878 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0
#> Duster 360          -0.96078893  1.0148821 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0
#> Merc 240D            0.71501778 -1.2248578 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0
#> Merc 230             0.44954345 -1.2248578 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0
#> Merc 280            -0.14777380 -0.1049878 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0
#> Merc 280C           -0.38006384 -0.1049878 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0
#> Merc 450SE          -0.61235388  1.0148821 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0
#> Merc 450SL          -0.46302456  1.0148821 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0
#> Merc 450SLC         -0.81145962  1.0148821 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0
#> Cadillac Fleetwood  -1.60788262  1.0148821 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0
#> Lincoln Continental -1.60788262  1.0148821 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0
#> Chrysler Imperial   -0.89442035  1.0148821 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0
#> Fiat 128             2.04238943 -1.2248578  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1
#> Honda Civic          1.71054652 -1.2248578  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1
#> Toyota Corolla       2.29127162 -1.2248578  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1
#> Toyota Corona        0.23384555 -1.2248578 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0
#> Dodge Challenger    -0.76168319  1.0148821 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0
#> AMC Javelin         -0.81145962  1.0148821 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0
#> Camaro Z28          -1.12671039  1.0148821 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0
#> Pontiac Firebird    -0.14777380  1.0148821 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0
#> Fiat X1-9            1.19619000 -1.2248578  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1
#> Porsche 914-2        0.98049211 -1.2248578 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1
#> Lotus Europa         1.71054652 -1.2248578  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1
#> Ford Pantera L      -0.71190675  1.0148821 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1
#> Ferrari Dino        -0.06481307 -0.1049878 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1
#> Maserati Bora       -0.84464392  1.0148821 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1
#> Volvo 142E           0.21725341 -1.2248578 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1
#>                     gear carb
#> Mazda RX4              4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag          4    4
#> Datsun 710             4    1
#> Hornet 4 Drive         3    1
#> Hornet Sportabout      3    2
#> Valiant                3    1
#> Duster 360             3    4
#> Merc 240D              4    2
#> Merc 230               4    2
#> Merc 280               4    4
#> Merc 280C              4    4
#> Merc 450SE             3    3
#> Merc 450SL             3    3
#> Merc 450SLC            3    3
#> Cadillac Fleetwood     3    4
#> Lincoln Continental    3    4
#> Chrysler Imperial      3    4
#> Fiat 128               4    1
#> Honda Civic            4    2
#> Toyota Corolla         4    1
#> Toyota Corona          3    1
#> Dodge Challenger       3    2
#> AMC Javelin            3    2
#> Camaro Z28             3    4
#> Pontiac Firebird       3    2
#> Fiat X1-9              4    1
#> Porsche 914-2          5    2
#> Lotus Europa           5    2
#> Ford Pantera L         5    4
#> Ferrari Dino           5    6
#> Maserati Bora          5    8
#> Volvo 142E             4    2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I fully agree with the criticism of my posted example, I should have put more thought into that. I aimed to reduced the needed coding effort for the people who were interested in this, but you broked down the problem concisely and without having to refer to imagined constraints. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @GregorThomas that `across` is the obvious solution to your question as posted and with @MrFlick that you should modify your post to make your intent clear.  That said, and based on your comments, I believe this gives you what you want (and is more in keeping with the tidyverse's style than your example).

```
scale_cols <- function(data, cols) {
  for (c in cols) {
    data <- data %>% mutate({{c}} := scale({{c}}))
  }
  data
}

mtcars %>% scale_cols(vars(mpg, cyl))
                            mpg        cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4            0.15088482 -0.1049878 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag        0.15088482 -0.1049878 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710           0.44954345 -1.2248578 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive       0.21725341 -0.1049878 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout   -0.23073453  1.0148821 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant             -0.33028740 -0.1049878 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
<output truncated for brevity>
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you for your comment. I realize that the example was poor as there are much simpler solutions to the posted code, but it was the easiest way to reproduce my local problem with as little coding effort as possible for the people who try to help.